# How write Bash script to find files then move them?

Tags: bash

I want to find files then move them, how can I do in in a Bash script?

```
find $PATH -type f -newermt "1 day ago" -exec gzip {} \;
```

Then:

```
find $PATH -type f -newermt "1 day ago" -exem mv {} \;
```

Try to add these lines in Bash script but I don't know how.

Comment: Apart from the misspelled `exec` and the suspicious use of `$PATH`, what’s stopping you from just adding those lines to the script?!

Answer (score 1):

May be you want to split `PATH` variable content before use it, like this:

```bash
find ${PATH//:/ } -type f -newermt "1 day ago" -exec gzip {} \;
```

Warning about your second command: `find $PATH -type f -newermt "1 day ago" -exem mv {} \;`. The option is `-exec`, not `-exem`.

`mv` command accept 2 file arguments. You pass only one.

Before execute your commands, you could place an `echo` command just after `-exec` option.

Comment: While this question is specific to bash, it's always worth noting the substitution form of the parameter expansion `${PATH//:/ }` is limited to bash. Those new to *shell* scripting often fail to appreciate the difference in shell capabilities between POSIX and the more advanced shells like bash. Otherwise, you cover all salient points nicely.

Comment: You have tagged your question only with bash. Expansion `${PATH//:/ }` also works with ksh and zsh. Expansion `${PATH//:/ }` works fine in POSIX mode (command: `bash --posix`)

Comment: That's all that is needed. Just something to let them know not all shells support all features.